# Heroku's domain mysite.herokuapp.com displays in browser after domain forwarding

Tags: heroku, dns, subdomain

Just bought a new domain on https://iwantmyname.com/. For the purpose of this post lets assume the domain is `example.fm`

I set up domain forwarding where I got example.fm to point to `example.herokuapp.com`. Everything seems to work, but after the site is forwarded, the browsers textbox displays the old `example.herokuapp.com` domain instead of `example.fm`

I already added example.fm to heroku with `heroku domains:add example.fm`, but that didn't seem to change anything.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I regularly set up websites whose domain is bought from `iwantmyname.com` for friends and have their website hosted on heroku. While your specific problem has never happened to me, I would highly recommend contacting their support. Any problem I have has been answered from the CEO/owner/founder of `iwantmyname.com` within hours of filing the ticket. They're support has been fantastic on my end, to say the least.

Comment: I have sent them a ticket, thanks! Hopefully I can get an answer either here or from them shortly :). I am curious if this is more of a heroku setup issue, though.

Comment: hey @ApathyBear, awesome! hopefully they'll get back to you ASAP! :0) If support provides a reasoning/explanation, and if you have time, I would love to know what the root cause of this was!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the people at iwantmyname.com have been extremely helpful.

It turns out that I only did URL forwarding, which isn't the recommended way of setting up a domain through them.

They have a specific system with dealing with heroku here: [mysite.herokuapp.com](http://mysite.herokuapp.com)

I got rid of the forwarding and set up my domain completely through Heroku custom domain DNS setup.